# RSA factorization knowing the form of p and q

Tags: rsa, factoring

I'm wondering if knowing the form of both factors (p and q) of a RSA modulus N is a significant help for factoring or not.

For instance:
p of the form 4k+3, so (p-3)%4 = 0
and q of the form 4k+7, so (q-7)%4 = 0

Comment: Note that the forms '4k+3' and '4k+7' are precisely the same...

Answer (score 4):

If $k$ is the same in the two forms, that is $n=(4k+3)(4k+7)$, factorization is trivial: $p=\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil-2$, $q=p+4$.

Assuming the two $k$ are independent from now on: note that for odd primes $p$ of a given size, the quantity $p\bmod4$ is about evenly split in $\{1,3\}$. Thus the known form gives one bit worth of information about $p$. We get that same bit of information about $q$, but observing $n\equiv1\pmod4$ already allowed to deduce it from $p\equiv3\pmod4$. Hence the known form gives only 1 bit of information towards helping factor $n$: for a given $n$ it can at best half the work. Also about one $n$ out of four in a normal RSA modulus has this form, thus if the problem was easy for these $n$, RSA would be insecure.